# The annotation "@mixin" in class Carbon\\Carbon was never imported

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, doctrine, php-carbon

I migrated my Symfony project from 5.2 to 5.4 with PHP 8.1. I use Carbon nesbot/carbon.

I have the error.

> [Semantical Error] The annotation "@mixin" in class Carbon\Carbon
> was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement
> for this annotation?

In my Kernel, I add in Kernel::configureContainer

```
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('mixin');
AnnotationReader::addGlobalIgnoredName('alias');
```

Why do I still get the error when these annotations should be disabled?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Only the one I posted years ago

Answer (score -1):

Solution is simple ..

I move AnnotationReader to to the top of configureContainer. Before services loading